# How to exclude a specific string with REGEX? (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

For example, I have these strings

```
APPLEJUCE1A
APPLETREE2B
APPLECAKE3C
APPLETEA1B
APPLEWINE3B
APPLEWINE1C
```

I want all of these strings except those that have `TEA` or `WINE1C` in them.

```
APPLEJUCE1A
APPLETREE2B
APPLECAKE3C
APPLEWINE3B
```

I've already tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
^APPLE(?!.*(?:TEA|WINE1C)).*$
```

Any help is appreciated as I'm also kinda new to this.

Comment: Use a RE that matches what you want to exclude, and then only allow things that fail to match.

Comment: Your pattern seem to work https://regex101.com/r/ejIpEV/1 Are these not the expected matches?

Comment: For example, `perl -ne 'print unless /TEA|WINE1C/' input.txt`

Comment: `^((?!TEA|WINE1C).)*$`

Comment: There are no strings that have both TEA and WINE1C in it.

Comment: @Thefourthbird it is `TEA` or `WINE1C` and not `TEA` and `WINE1C`

Comment: @onyambu The question was really poorly worded initially. This has been fixed.

Comment: @onyambu That is not in the initial question, the way that is has been edited now changes the question. And if it is OR, then the original pattern of the OP should just work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you indeed have mutliple strings as you claim, there's no need to jam all that in one regex pattern.

```perl
/^APPLE/ && !/TEA|WINE1C/
```

If you have a single string, the best approach is probably to splice it into lines (`split /\n/`), but you could also use a single regex match too

```perl
/^APPLE(?!.*TEA|WINE1C).*/mg
```

Comment: I favor the two regex solution. It's harder to screw up that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^APPLE(?!.*TEA)(?!.*WINE1C).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YNuuHj/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `APPLE` - a fixed string
- `(?!.*TEA)` - no `TEA` allowed anywhere to the right of the current location
- `(?!.*WINE1C)` - no `WINE1C` allowed anywhere to the right of the current location
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to match a string that has both or them (which is not in the current example data):

```
^APPLE(?!.*(WINE1C|TEA).*(?!\1)(?:TEA|WINE1C)).*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `APPLE` match literally
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `.*(WINE1C|TEA)` Capture either one of the values in group 1
  - `.*` Match 0+ characters
  - `(?!\1)(?:TEA|WINE1C)` Match either one of the values as long as it is not the same as previously matched in group 1
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `.*` Match the rest of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/03QnW5/1)